# Can't simulate click on submit button via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I'm having problems simulating a click via javascript on a mailchimp pop-up subscribe form and i need your help.

```
    <!-- Title & Description - Holds HTML from CK editor -->
    <div class="content__titleDescription" data-dojo-attach-point="descriptionContainer"><strong>Unlock the content </strong>by subscribing to our page.</div>

    <!-- Form Fields -->
    <form action="//mc.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/form-post?u=bcd9828fa83ea7a231ffbee26&amp;id=1928481ac4" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-dojo-attach-point="formNode" novalidate="">
        <div class="content__formFields" data-dojo-attach-point="formFieldsContainer">
            <div class="field-wrapper" id="uniqName_3_0" widgetid="uniqName_3_0">
                <label for="mc-EMAIL">Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="EMAIL" value="" id="mc-EMAIL" class="invalid">
                <div class="invalid-error" style="display: block;">This field is required.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="field-wrapper" id="uniqName_3_1" widgetid="uniqName_3_1">
                <label for="mc-FNAME">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="FNAME" value="" id="mc-FNAME" class="valid">
                <div class="invalid-error" style="display: none;"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="position:absolute;left:-5000px;">
                <input type="text" name="b_bcd9828fa83ea7a231ffbee26_1928481ac4" tabindex="-1" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content__button">
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Subscribe" data-dojo-attach-point="submitButton">
        </div>
    </form>

    <!-- Footer - Holds HTML from CK editor -->
    <div class="content__footer" data-dojo-attach-point="footerContainer"></div>
</div>
<div class="modalContent__image" data-dojo-attach-point="formImageContainer"></div>
```

The code that i'm trying to target is:

```
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Subscribe" data-dojo-attach-point="submitButton">
```

It's the submit button "Subscribe" that you can also see in

http://www.aspeagro.com/EN_Program_Abricot.html

Thank you!

Comment: I looked at that link and saw the popup, but it looks like it's submitting correctly on click, so I think I'm missing what functionality it is that you're missing. What is your intended behavior exactly, and how is it not currently doing it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That button is inside an iframe. To access it from the parent page you would trigger it like this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('input:submit').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

set `id="btn"` attribute to your submitting button and using jQuery you can trigger click with `$("#btn").click();` call

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I think is should do what you're after?

**HTML**

```
<input id="submit-button" class="button" type="submit" value="Subscribe" data-dojo-attach-point="submitButton">
```

**JS**

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    // Do what you want to do
});
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to simulate a click event, whereas binding a click event assumes the user has already clicked the button.

Comment: @Gherghescu Valentin, can you clarify please

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to submit the form, then don't bother sending a click event, but use the form's submit method:

```
var form = document.getElementById('uniqName_3_0').parentNode.parentNode;
form.submit();
```

The code is of course easier if you give the form an id attribute:

```
<form id="myform" ...
```

and then:

```
document.getElementById('myform').submit();
```